# Pygame physics simulation

Tags: python, physics, simulation, pygame

How do I show the trajectory in the background as a projectile travels(airbone) using pygame ?
Also how would i add input boxes that can take center of mass and make changes to the trajectory ? Thanks for the help

Comment: so far the ball follows gravity laws and comes to rest but i cant see a trajectory(bcos i dont know to code for it )

Comment: Show code or it didn't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every timestep save the position of the object into a list. Then draw lines, beginning at the first item of the list. Consider the following raw example, of how it might look like.

```
class MyBall(object):
    ...
    def update(self, dt):
        ...
        self.trajectory.append(self.position)

    def draw(self, surface):
        pygame.draw.lines(surface, somecolor, self.trajectory)
```

Comment: I am getting an error in the draw function, and do i call draw once or each time( discrete execution ).

Comment: class Particle:
    def __init__(self,(x,y),size):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.size=size
        self.colour=(0,0,255)
        self.thickness=1
        self.speed=0
        self.angle=0
        self.trajectory=[(x,y)]